# How can I add a QLineEdit to Menubar

Tags: qt, qt4, menubar, qlineedit

I am attempting to reclaim some screen real estate in my application. I've got a search bar that is a basic QLineEdit and takes up space. In my menu bar, I easily have enough room to fit this search box, but I can't figure out how to get the LineEdit into the menubar.

Can someone assist me in getting this added to a menubar?

I am using Qt 4.7.

Here is an image of what I am attempting to accomplish. It's fairly basic image, but I'm looking to use the right half of the menubar as a search box.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [QWidgetAction](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidgetaction.html). QWidgetAction is for inserting custom widgets into action based containers, such as toolbars.

here is an example to add a progressbar to menu bar :

```
QWidgetAction *widgetAction = new QWidgetAction(this);
widgetAction->setDefaultWidget(new QProgressBar(this));
menubar.addAction(widgetAction);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use

void QMenuBar::setCornerWidget ( QWidget * widget, Qt::Corner corner = Qt::TopRightCorner )

to add your widget in the menu.

Comment: Wow.. After more than a half day of different trials and errors this simple method solved my problem :-)  
(I needed to add a clock to the right corner of my application on the same "line" with the menubar)

Thanks!